# F# in VS2015 : Intellisense

Tags: compiler-errors, f#, intellisense

Sometimes, Intellisense is signaling errors in my source code, underlying a few stuff in RED, and the error list is not empty. But the code does compile and execute without any problem

It always has to do with opening a library
for example `Open Spreads` in the main.fs file. This will be red-underlined as well as a few calls to that library (not all of them)

I have a separate .fsx file which in the Solution Explorer is placed above the main.fs file

the .fsx file will contain

```
#I "\...\packages\Spreads.0.3.5\lib\net45"
#r "\...\packages\Spreads.0.3.5\lib\net45\Spreads.dll"
```

Am I doing the things wrong ?

Comment: I've seen that occasionally. In my case, unloading and reloading the project, while keeping the solution open, makes the errors disappear.

Comment: No. If you are building a project the only errors you should be concerned with are the ones from the compiler. I can't find the source document but Intellisense has to work differently than the parser to produce information when there are errors in the source code as such this is one of the side effects.

Comment: If you specify `#I @"\...\packages\Spreads.0.3.5\lib\net45"` then `#r "Spreads.dll"` should be enough. The above comments are correct but I would like to add that you should use @ in front of path names. Also the behaviour you see has probably to do with mixing fs and fsx files. Make sure you also `#load` the files and if there is a library dll add the Reference in VS directly.

Comment: The build action for fsx files is None in VS btw.